# Show HTML text with met Javascript conditions?

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to gain the basic functionality of validating whether a correct answer was chosen or not by changing the style of the text, however, **I wanted to know if it's possible to have a phrase appear upon achieving a perfect score.** With the given sample code from the site (linked at the bottom of the question), I see that a score is able to be tracked. Due to this, I was wondering, is there a method or function that I could use to incorporate this action?

As for my own testing, I gave the text I want to display upon the met condition an id of "demo" and gave it an opacity value of 0 within the style sheet. After that, I added the variable `NumWrong` in order to track the number of incorrect answers; I originally attempted to make a function that would change the text's opacity but I am not good at functions and it ultimately failed. I also potentially had the idea of declaring a value to be false until a score (which is tracked by `numCorrect`) Due to this, I decided to reach out to the community in an attempt to gain a new understanding of JavaScript/Website logic.

I have attached my code at the bottom of this question which contains the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files while also attaching a link to the code I based this project on under this line. If you need to test out the code, the correct answer for all 6 questions is A.

https://simplestepscode.com/javascript-quiz-tutorial/

> TLDR: 
> I wanted to know if it's possible to have a phrase appear upon achieving a perfect score.

```js
var myQuestions = [{
    question: "Q1",
    answers: {
      A: 'A',
      B: 'B',
      C: 'C',
      D: 'D'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'A',
    wrongAnswers: 'B, C, D'
  },
  {
    question: "Q2",
    answers: {
      A: 'A',
      B: 'B',
      C: 'C',
      D: 'D'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'A',
    wrongAnswers: 'B, C, D'
  },
  {
    question: "Q3",
    answers: {
      A: 'A',
      B: 'B',
      C: 'C',
      D: 'D'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'A',
    wrongAnswers: 'B, C, D'
  },
  {
    question: "Q4",
    answers: {
      A: 'A',
      B: 'B',
      C: 'C',
      D: 'D'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'A',
    wrongAnswers: 'B, C, D'
  },
  {
    question: "Q5",
    answers: {
      A: 'A',
      B: 'B',
      C: 'C',
      D: 'D'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'A',
    wrongAnswers: 'B, C, D'
  },
  {
    question: "Q6",
    answers: {
      A: 'A',
      B: 'B',
      C: 'C',
      D: 'D'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'A',
    wrongAnswers: 'B, C, D'
  }
];

var quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
var resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
var winCondition = document.getElementById('demo')

generateQuiz(myQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton);

function generateQuiz(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton) {

  function showQuestions(questions, quizContainer) {

    var output = [];
    var answers;


    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {


      answers = [];


      for (letter in questions[i].answers) {

        answers.push(
          '<label>' +
          '<input type="radio" name="question' + i + '" value="' + letter + '">' +
          letter + ': ' +
          questions[i].answers[letter] +
          '</label>'
        );
      }

      output.push(
        '<div class="question">' + questions[i].question + '</div>' +
        '<div class="answers">' + answers.join('') + '</div>'
      );
    }

    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
  }


  function showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer) {

    var answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

    var userAnswer = '';
    var numCorrect = 0;
    var numWrong = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

      userAnswer = (answerContainers[i].querySelector('input[name=question' + i + ']:checked') || {}).value;

      if (userAnswer === questions[i].correctAnswer) {

        numCorrect++;


        answerContainers[i].style.color = 'lightgreen';
      } else {
        answerContainers[i].style.color = 'red';
        numWrong++;
      }
      resultsContainer.innerHTML = numCorrect + ' out of ' + questions.length;

    }


  }


  showQuestions(questions, quizContainer);

  submitButton.onclick = function() {
    showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(120, 10, 148);
}

.question {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: violet;
}

.answers {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.question,
.answers {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#submit {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: yellow;
}

#demo {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="quiz"></div>
  <p id="demo">This text should appear upon a 6 out of 6</p>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script src="app.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

After the line where you change resultsContainer.innerHtml add:

```
if (numCorrect == 6){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.opacity = 1;}
```

That should do the trick.

Basically, you can access and manipulate all css properties of a given element via the style attribute of the element. I see you already declared winCondition to be the desired element and you can in fact reuse this variable here instead of calling getElementById again (I highly recommend reusing it). However, you are missing a semicolon after declaring winCondition. Except for that, it looks fine.